Power Automate Trigger Condition Action rate limit is exceeded;
I have a column named "Tracking Number" in my SharePoint library, and I want to run a flow only when the Tracking Number contains a semicolon.
The issue is that I built a flow to replace semicolons with commas in the SharePoint library, which has around 50000 records. However, because of the Power Automate limitation, the flow fails with a status code 429 error ("rate limit is exceeded; try again in 59 seconds"). To avoid this error, I plan to add a condition before the action to target only the columns with semicolons.


Which trigger are you using? You want to add expression in trigger condition or inside "condition" action?

If I run this WF, I will get an error message (the "rate limit is exceeded; try again in 59 seconds") that hits API for more than I should. To avoid the flow from go and check all the records, I was hoping I could add a condition after the Get Files action to check only the records with a semicolon
